# Python format and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to drop some columns using format.(want to drop columns: new_cost0, new_0_quantity, new_2_cost, and new_2_quantity) But not every column is dropped. Below is the data frame and codes.

dataFrame

```
    |new_0_cost|new_0_quantity|new_2_cost|new_2_quantity|quality|weights|     
   0| 10       | 20           |  10      | 20           | good  | 40    |
```

function

```
def drop_cost_and_quan(data):
    # data is a dataframe described above
    # try to drop new_cost0, new_0_quantity, new_2_cost, and new_2_quantity
    data3 = data.copy()
    for i, item in enumerate(data3.columns):
        if item == 'new_{0}_cost'.format(i):
            data3 = data3.drop(item, axis=1)
        print('cost:',item == 'new_{0}_cost'.format(i))

    for i, item in enumerate(data3.columns):
        if item == 'new_{0}_quantity'.format(i):
            data3 = data3.drop(item, axis=1)
        print(item == 'item_{0}_quantity'.format(i))

    return data3
```

Outptut:

```
data3 = drop_cost_and_quan(data):

cost: True
cost: False
cost: True
cost: False
cost: False
cost: False
quntity: True
quntity: False
quntity: False
quntity: False

data3 
 |new_2_quantity|quality| weights|
0| 20           |good   |40
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

alternatively to @vinod's method you can also do it this way:

```
In [148]: df
Out[148]:
   new_0_cost  new_0_quantity  new_2_cost  new_2_quantity  new_0_total_cost  new_2_total_cost quality  weights
0          10              20          10              20              1111              2222    good       40

In [151]: df.drop(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(r'^new_\d+_(?:quantity|cost)')], 1, inplace=True)

In [152]: df
Out[152]:
   new_0_total_cost  new_2_total_cost quality  weights
0              1111              2222    good       40
```

Explanation:

```
In [148]: df
Out[148]:
   new_0_cost  new_0_quantity  new_2_cost  new_2_quantity  new_0_total_cost  new_2_total_cost quality  weights
0          10              20          10              20              1111              2222    good       40

In [149]: df.columns.str.contains(r'^new_\d+_(?:quantity|cost)')
Out[149]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [150]: df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(r'^new_\d+_(?:quantity|cost)')]
Out[150]: Index(['new_0_cost', 'new_0_quantity', 'new_2_cost', 'new_2_quantity'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: for this method, if I have other columns called new_0_total_cost, and new_2_total_cost and I don't want to drop the columns(drop only quantity, cost columns, not new_0_total_cost, new_2_total_cost columns), how can I modify the code you wrote?

Comment: @K.heer, you don't have to modify it, it'll work correctly - check update

Comment: I add | after cost by mistake, which drops mosts of the columns. Thank you!

Comment: but do you know why new_{0}_quantity'.format(i) does't work ?

Comment: @K.heer, i don't know, but you can easily debug it - add `print('col#: {}, col_name: {}'.format(i, item))` to your loop

Answer (score 2):

Use `del df['column_name']` to delete column

to delete multiple columns

```
df.drop([col for col in ['column_name1','column_name2']],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `filter`

***setup***

```
data = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        new_0_cost=[10, 10],
        new_0_quantity=[20, 20],
        new_2_cost=[10, 10],
        new_2_quantity=[20, 20],
        quality=['good', 'good'],
        weights=[40, 40],
        new_0_total_cost=[1, 2],
        new_2_total_cost =[3, 4]  
    ))

data
```

[image]

---

```
data.filter(regex=r'^(?!new_\d+_(?:quantity|cost))')
```

[image]

Comment: yeah, first i thought to use `filter()` too, but i personally don't like negative lookahead RegEx's - sometimes it's painful to change them. +1